# Ubuntu Tornado Webserver modules ImportError

Tags: python, tornado, importerror, easy-install

These are the steps I have done:

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev python-setuptools
easy_install mechanize lxml tornado
```

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import lxml.html
import mechanize
import tornado.web
```

Runs the script:

```
python tornado.py
```

And this is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tornado.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tornado.web
  File "/root/scripts/tornado.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tornado.web
ImportError: No module named web
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your source file is called `tornado.py`. Therefore python confuses it with the `tornado` library. Use another filename for your file, e.g. `mytornadoapp.py`.